# COMException at RaiseCanExecuteChanged at UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a RelayCommand, binded to an AppBarButton, as:

```
Command="{Binding NextCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

The command's CanExecute property is just a simple null check.

```
private bool CanExecuteNextCommand() => !(this.SelectedItem == null);
```

But, if the RaiseCanExecuteChanged gets called (via Trigger) quickly, multiple times, then here:

```
CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

I get the following exception:

"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

If I remove the Command property binding from the view, it works.

I even tried adding a Task.Delay(200) before Raising the CanExecuteChangeds at the trigger, but I get the same exception.

Has anyone encountered something like this in UWP?

Comment: Not sure if the issue was in your own code. What's the trigger? Please share a [mcve] with us.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you would put `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on a command binding! Normally, a command never changes (but nothing stops you of having logic inside the command execution method!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**According to this:** https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cfa7416c-435f-4f4b-9ad0-2b290b4ee978/w81-windows-81-app-working-properly-in-windows-81-throws-comexception-0x80004005-when-it-is?forum=wpdevelop

I'm having the same situation, the command that's CanExecuteChanged is about to get invoked is not on the same views as the current view one on the screen.

**As a solution:** I just put the CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); into a try, with an empty catch block for the COMException:

```
catch(System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex) { }
```